# Resistivity of Ferromagnetic Substance

Tags: resistivity

How does the resistivity of a ferromagnetic material change as the material is being magnetized (magnetic domains aligned)?

Comment: Good question. What does your research so far tell you about it?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple magnetoresistive effects which depend on the material mostly. For ferromagnetic material, static magnetic fields and very thin layers, the [GMR effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_magnetoresistance) is relevant.

As soon the ferromagnetic conductor is more than a few millimeters thick and AC comes into play (50Hz suffices), that effect is outplayed by the [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), which is enormous for ferromagnetic materials.